# After submiting form the script is triggered again

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, post

When I click the button with AJAX POST script more then once the script is triggered again. For example If I try to create an item, it is created twice or more times. How to resolve this problem?

```
      $(document).delegate(".add_page_submit","click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        var target = ".add_page_lightbox";
        var formData = new FormData($("#add_page_form")[0]);
        var content = editor.val();
        formData.append('content', content);

        var page_title = $("#add_page_form input[name='title']").val();
        var chapter_id = $("#add_page_chapter_select").val();

        $.ajax
        ({
          url: $root + 'php/add_page.php',
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData:false,
          success: function(data)
          {
            if(data == 'sucsess')
            {
              alert(data);
              close_lightbox(target);

              $(".chapters_list .chapter_item[ch_id='" + chapter_id + "']").children(".pages_list").append("" + page_title + "Остановть");
            }
            else if(data == 'false')
            {
              alert(data);
            };
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: delegate has been deprecated and also put all your code on jsfiddle to get help very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Your script is executed whenever the button is clicked. Adding the disabled attribute doesn't stop you from clicking it so the `click` event is still triggered. In the begining of your handler you should check if the button is disabled:

```
$(document).delegate(".add_page_submit","click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).prop('disabled')) return;
```

It would be different if you used the `submit` event of a form. In that case clicking on a disabled `[type="submit"]` button won't trigger the `submit` event of the form and you wouldn't have to make the manual check, pointed above.

Comment: I try it, but it dosen't resolve the problem. In FIREBUG when i click submit button second time it is send 2 POST request. If I click it third time if send 4 POST request, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you verify if it has been submitted before sending the next request?

Like:

```js
var formSubmitted = false;
$(".add_page_submit").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // returns if the form is submitting
  if(formSubmitted) return;

  //else, start submit
  formSubmitted = true;
  $(this).prop('disabled', true); //disables input
 /* do ajax stuff */
  $.ajax({
    url: $root + 'php/add_page.php',
    ...
    success: function(data){
      ...
      formSubmitted = false;
      $(this).prop('disabled', false); //re-enables input
      // here you can also clear the form

    }
  });


});
```